# Largest Circle under Bell curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the largest circle symmetrical to y-axis and touching x-axis at bottom and   Bell curve on sides given in its standard form (a=1):

$$ y/a= e^ {\frac{-x^2}{2 \sigma^2} }. $$

> EDIT 1: Motivation for question : Why does it touch at $ x = \pm
>   \sigma? EDIT 2:  (The error realized after posting, but refrained from
>   deleting a part of an answered question)

Comment: I believe, that is a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115226/largest-circle-between-y-xn-and-y-sqrtnx

Comment: Similar is not same. I find several users showing interest in probability, LM etc. Asked the question specially to focus on the curve construction mode, to get a feel and so on..

Answer (score 1):

If my computations are right, it doesn't touch at $\pm \sigma$. Let $\sigma = 1$. Let $(u,v)$ be the tangency point in the first quadrant, and $R$ the radius of the circle. Then $u^2 + (v-R)^2 = R^2$, $v = e^{-\frac{u^2} 2}$, and the tangency condition gives $-vu = -\frac u {v-R}$. From the last equation, $R = v - \frac 1 v$. Substitute in the first equation, simplify to get $u^2 = v^2 - 2$. Substitute in $v = e^{-\frac {u^2} 2}$ to conclude $u^2 + 2 = e^{-u^2}$. Solve this equation to find the "$u$" of the tangency point; $u=1$ is NOT the solution.

Comment: Yes, I realized this soon after posting. How is the tangentcy condition obtained?

Comment: First, I missed the factor of $\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}$, but this won't save it. Second, the tangency condition: I equate the slopes. For the Gaussian function, $y' = - xy$ and for the circle, $2x + 2y'(y-R) = 0$; $y'$ must be the same at $(u,v)$.

Comment: However you have not found a numerical value for u. No problem. When I tried, I don't get any real value for $u$ ! Please check.

Comment: I didn't - you get an equation that does not have a closed-form solution, you can only find it numerically (by approximation). There is, though, a unique tangency circle like you described - this can be shown by continuity (let R go from zero to infinity).

Comment: Not sure you understood.  $ u^2 + 2 = e^{-u^2}$ has no real roots !!

Comment: Maximum radius may be only  $\frac12$ between Bell top-point and origin.

Comment: Right, and right; I must have messed up a sign somewhere, because a tangent circle must exist. For the function without dividing by $\frac 1 {\sqrt{2 \pi}}$, I wonder if it's not the circle of radius $\frac 1 2$ with center at $(0, \frac 1 2)$!

Comment: ?? Certainly not from me!